# How to Keep all Filters Visible in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation

Is it possible to keep all filters visible in the Layered Navigation even when one or more are active.

[image]

Currently I have built a navigation with category and product attribute filters. By default when a filter is active it vanishes. But I need to keep them alway visible so I can build a navigation like below.

[image]

Comment: Used this as Solution: https://gist.github.com/mhauri/93bc9ffe87250a55d5bb7eda4a85cd40

Answer (score 1):

Default Magento does not have this feature,you need to use any 3rd prty extension or need to do customization.

My preference is  [Amasty Improved Layered Navigation](https://amasty.com/improved-layered-navigation-for-magento-2.html). But not sure 100%.

Answer (score 0):

You can use free extension for complete this task.

Please check this free extension.

http://www.manadev.com/magento-2-user-guides/multiple-select-for-layered-navigation-filters/what-is-layered-navigation-in-magento-2

Let me know if you have any query.